# convert an array for strings to strings bicep

Tags: arrays, azure-bicep

I would like to be able to convert an array to strings i bicep

Let say i have an array:

```html
    param arraytest array = [
    'numberOne'
    'numberTwo'
    ]
```

I would like to be able to convert this array to strings, så when i put the arraytest in a new array, that only excepts strings, it will not complain

so like this:

```html
    destination: [
    arraytest 
    'numberThree'
    ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate array ? Sorry it's unclear what your asking but the answer from @JustAGuy should help if you d like to concatenate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the concat function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#concat

```
var destination = concat(arraytest, [
'numberThree'
])
```